# Access Selenium ChromeDriver from another project in the same solution C# VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I have a solution, there are two projects in it. First one is a console application where the instance of ChromeDriver is created and the second one a WinForm application. I need to get an access from the WinForm application to the created instance of the ChromeDriver.

I've created the code which works as I expect except the button click opens another window of Chrome browser which I don't need.

How can I access the existing chrome driver without creating another instance?

First project:

```
public static OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver ChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Программинг\с\new_shit\TFR\TFR_cons\bin\Debug");
public static IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)ChromeDriver; // Make JS instance for JS execution
```

Second project:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Add bought
{
    int MessagesOnThePage = TFR_cons.Program.ChromeDriver.FindElementsByClassName("GLS-JUXDKAD").Count;
    MessageBox.Show("Elements found: " + MessagesOnThePage);
}
```

Comment: Guys, anybody knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, linking the two projects together happens in chrome, but you need direct access. You can achieve this in VS by [right click on the project] --> add --> reference --> project --> (select the project that contains the chrome driver instance).

After this, you can simply access it by a using myNamespace; and than naming it.

If I misunderstood the problem, please comment under this answer so I can delete it.

Comment: The reference is already there. Thx for the answer. And as I discovered, after clicking the button not only Chrome browser is opening - the whole copy of project 1 is being created including another console window.

Comment: I think if this was not the problem, we're heading out of my area of expertise, so you'll have to get your answers from someone else.